# How can I call a procedure declared inside another procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, call, procedure, declare

I have a doubt regarding procedures in Db2. I created a stored procedure using "CREATE PROCEDURE", and inside that I have another which is declared using "DECLARE PROCEDURE". But, this procedure created by declare, cannot be called using "CALL".

When I try to run the procedure,  Db2 returns:

> [Code: -440, SQL State: 42884]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-440,
>   SQLSTATE=42884,
>   SQLERRMC=DMTLDBR.SP_DASH_CALENDARIO.PROCURA_DIA_UTIL_POST_DIA1;PROCEDURE,
>   DRIVER=4.25.1301

How should I  call the declared procedure? (PROCURA_DIA_UTIL_POST_DIA1)

Code:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE           "SP_DASH_CALENDARIO" (IN P_MES INTEGER)
BEGIN

------
DECLARE SQLSTATE                       CHAR(5) DEFAULT ' ';

DECLARE V_ANO_MES                      DECIMAL(6); 
DECLARE V_ID_DIA                       ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_DIM_DIADIA.ID_DIA;

DECLARE V_VAL_REAL_CAL                 ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_FATO_VENDASDIARIO.VAL_TONLIQUIDO;
DECLARE V_VAL_TONVNEMA                 ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_FATO_VENDASDIARIO.VAL_TONVNEMA;
DECLARE V_VAL_FAT357_CAL               ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_FATO_VENDASDIARIO.VAL_FAT357; 
DECLARE V_VAL_PERDA_FAT_CAL            ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_FATO_VENDASDIARIO.VAL_PERDA;

DECLARE V_SUM_VAL_REAL_CAL             ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_FATO_DASH_CALENDARIO.VAL_REAL_CAL;
DECLARE V_SUM_VAL_TONVNE_CAL           ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_FATO_DASH_CALENDARIO.VAL_TONVNE_CAL;
DECLARE V_SUM_VAL_TONLIQUIDO_ZBCL_CAL  ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_FATO_DASH_CALENDARIO.VAL_TONLIQUIDO_ZBCL_CAL;
DECLARE V_SUM_VAL_TONLIQUIDO_CAL       ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_FATO_DASH_CALENDARIO.VAL_TONLIQUIDO_CAL;
DECLARE V_SUM_VAL_FAT357_CAL           ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_FATO_DASH_CALENDARIO.VAL_FAT357_CAL;   

DECLARE V_VAL_TONLIQUIDO_CAL           ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_FATO_DASH_CALENDARIO.VAL_TONLIQUIDO_CAL;
DECLARE V_VAL_TONVNE_CAL               ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_FATO_DASH_CALENDARIO.VAL_TONVNE_CAL;
DECLARE V_VAL_TONLIQUIDO_ZBCL_CAL      ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_FATO_DASH_CALENDARIO.VAL_TONLIQUIDO_ZBCL_CAL; 

DECLARE V_VAL_PLANO_FAT_CAL            ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_FATO_PLANEJ_MAN.VAL_PLANO; 
DECLARE V_VAL_PLANO                    ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_FATO_PLANEJ_MAN.VAL_PLANO; 
DECLARE V_TOTAL_PLANO_DESOVA_SEMANAL   ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_FATO_PLANEJ_MAN.TOTAL_PLANO_DESOVA_SEMANAL;

DECLARE V_ID_DIASEMANA                 ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_DIM_DIADIA.ID_DIASEMANA;
DECLARE V_FLG_HOLIDAY                  ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_DIM_DIADIA.FLG_HOLIDAY;

DECLARE V_IND_LEGENDA                  DECIMAL(1);
DECLARE V_VARIANTE                     ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_DIM_PRODVARIANTE.ID_VARIANTE;

DECLARE V_VAL_PERDA                    ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_FATO_VENDASDIARIO.VAL_TONLIQUIDO;
DECLARE V_VAL_DESOVA                   ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_FATO_VENDASDIARIO.VAL_TONLIQUIDO;
DECLARE V_VAL_UHT                      ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_FATO_VENDASDIARIO.VAL_TONLIQUIDO;
DECLARE V_VAL_SUCO                     ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_FATO_VENDASDIARIO.VAL_TONLIQUIDO;
DECLARE V_VAL_REQ                      ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_FATO_VENDASDIARIO.VAL_TONLIQUIDO;
DECLARE V_FAT_UHT                      ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_FATO_VENDASDIARIO.VAL_FAT357;  
DECLARE V_FAT_REQ                      ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_FATO_VENDASDIARIO.VAL_FAT357; 


DECLARE V_ID_DIA_INI                   ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_DIM_DIADIA.ID_DIA;
DECLARE V_ID_DIA_FIM                   ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_DIM_DIADIA.ID_DIA;
DECLARE FLAG_DIA_UTIL                  BOOLEAN;
DECLARE V_SUM_VAL_TONVNEMA_CAL         ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_FATO_DASH_CALENDARIO.VAL_TONVNEMA_CAL;
DECLARE V_SUM_VAL_FAT357               ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_FATO_VENDASDIARIO.VAL_FAT357;
DECLARE V_SUM_VAL_ABATIMENTOREPORTADO  ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_FATO_VENDASDIARIO.VAL_ABATIMENTOREPORTADO;
DECLARE V_SUM_VAL_ICMSZFMREPORTADO     ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_FATO_VENDASDIARIO.VAL_ICMSZFMREPORTADO;

DECLARE V_PROC                         ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_TMP_LOG_EXECUTION_PROC.SYNCPOINT_PROC;
SET V_PROC = 'SP_DASH_CALENDARIO';

-- =========================================================================================================
--   P R O C   P R O C U R A _ D I A _ U T I L _ P O S T _ D I A 1
--
--  OBTEM O PRIMEIRO DIA ÚTIL DO MÊS (QUE NÃO SEJA DOMINGO NEM FERIADO)
--
-- =========================================================================================================
BEGIN
DECLARE PROCEDURE PROCURA_DIA_UTIL_POST_DIA1(IN P_ID_MES INTEGER)
BEGIN

        DECLARE V_ACHOU  DECIMAL(1) DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING, NOT FOUND BEGIN END;

        SET V_ID_DIA = NULL;

        L1: LOOP -- (LP01)

        BEGIN  -- (BE02.)

                DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' BEGIN END;

                SELECT MIN(ID_DIA) INTO V_ID_DIA
                FROM   DMTLDBR.TB_DIM_DIADIA
                WHERE  ID_MES     = P_ID_MES
                AND    ID_DIASEMANA  <> 1  -- DOMINGO
                AND    FLG_HOLIDAY = 0;

        END; -- (BE02.)

        IF SQLSTATE = '00000' THEN
                LEAVE L1;
         --SET V_ACHOU = 1;
        END IF;

        END LOOP L1; -- (LP01.)

END;
END;

CALL DMTLDBR.PROCURA_DIA_UTIL_POST_DIA1(201909);

END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have more than one mistake in the code shown in the question.

You are using a *local procedure*, that is the name for a procedure declared inside another procedure.

Local-Procedures work fine when used correctly.

Some suggestions to allow successful compilation:

- the `declare procedure` must appear before any executable statements or new block in the calling procedure.

  Move the statement `SET V_PROC = 'SP_DASH_CALENDARIO'` so that it appears 
  before the CALL to the local procedure (or anywhere within the main procedure block *AFTER*
  all declarations (including after declaring the local procedure).

  Additionally, remove the BEGIN (and matching END) on the line before `DECLARE PROCEDURE`.
  You want *all* the declares to appear before *any* executable statement or new begin-end block.
- the local procedure name must be unqualified *both* on the DECLARE *and* on the CALL
  but you are using a qualifier on your CALL statement which will prevent Db2 from finding the local procedure.

The **last part** of your procedure will then look something like below:

```
...snip...

DECLARE V_SUM_VAL_ICMSZFMREPORTADO     ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_FATO_VENDASDIARIO.VAL_ICMSZFMREPORTADO;
DECLARE V_PROC                         ANCHOR DATA TYPE TO DMTLDBR.TB_TMP_LOG_EXECUTION_PROC.SYNCPOINT_PROC;


    -- =========================================================================================================
    --   P R O C   P R O C U R A _ D I A _ U T I L _ P O S T _ D I A 1
    --
    --  OBTEM O PRIMEIRO DIA ÚTIL DO MÊS (QUE NÃO SEJA DOMINGO NEM FERIADO)
    --
    -- =========================================================================================================
    DECLARE PROCEDURE PROCURA_DIA_UTIL_POST_DIA1(IN P_ID_MES INTEGER)
    BEGIN

            DECLARE V_ACHOU  DECIMAL(1) DEFAULT 0;
            DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING, NOT FOUND BEGIN END;

            SET V_ID_DIA = NULL;

            L1: LOOP -- (LP01)

            BEGIN  -- (BE02.)

                    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' BEGIN END;

                    SELECT MIN(ID_DIA) INTO V_ID_DIA
                    FROM   DMTLDBR.TB_DIM_DIADIA
                    WHERE  ID_MES     = P_ID_MES
                    AND    ID_DIASEMANA  <> 1  -- DOMINGO
                    AND    FLG_HOLIDAY = 0;

            END; -- (BE02.)

            IF SQLSTATE = '00000' THEN
                    LEAVE L1;
             --SET V_ACHOU = 1;
            END IF;

            END LOOP L1; -- (LP01.)

    END;

    SET V_PROC = 'SP_DASH_CALENDARIO';

    CALL PROCURA_DIA_UTIL_POST_DIA1(201909);

    END@
```

Answer (score 1):

A [Compound SQL (compiled) statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004239.html) requires strict order of declarations / statements inside.
For example:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_LOCAL(P_I INT)
BEGIN
    -- SQL-variable-declarations
    DECLARE L_I INT;

    -- DECLARE-CURSOR-statements
    DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR VALUES 1;

    -- procedure-declaration
    DECLARE PROCEDURE TEST_LOCAL_NESTED(P_J INT) BEGIN END;

    -- handler-declarations
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION BEGIN END;

    -- SQL-procedure-statements
    CALL TEST_LOCAL_NESTED(P_I);
END@
```

Briefly for each `BEGIN END` block:

1-st: all `SQL-variable-declarations`
2-nd: all `DECLARE-CURSOR-statements`
3-rd: all `procedure-declaration`
4-th: all `handler-declarations`

All `SQL-procedure-statements` come afterwards only. These statements may contain nested `BEGIN END` blocks, where the same strict declaration / statement rules apply.